# Use external datafile in `learnr` exercise

Tags: r, learnr

I am trying to write a `learnr` tutorial in which one of the exercises is to import an SPSS dataset. From the `learnr` [documentation](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/learnr/articles/exercises.html):

> There are three ways authors can include files for use in exercises:
>
> 1. Store the files in a data/ directory in the same directory as the
>    tutorial.
> 2. Use the setup chunk to download or write the files to a data/
>    directory.
> 3. Use the tutorial.data_dir global option or the TUTORIAL_DATA_DIR
>    environment variables to specify a path to a data directory.

Following method #1 above, I have created a "data" directory within the directory that contains my .rmd file:

```
> list.files()
[1] "data"          "filemgmt.html" "filemgmt.Rmd" 
>
```

And the directory contains a file named "frm_wide.sav":

```
> list.files(path="./data", pattern="frm_wide.sav")
[1] "frm_wide.sav"
>
```

Now, when I run the `filemgmt.Rmd`, I get an error because the file is not found:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just got the right hint from the Rstudio community. Access to external data stored in the "/data" directory is a function that is still not present in the `learnr` version in the CRAN repository. I installed `learnr` from github (`devtools::install_github("rstudio/learnr")`) and now everything works as expected.